# Python manipulate byte string like string or parse in some way

Tags: python

I have several long byte strings from web socket data that I need to modify but I am unsure how I can achieve this. Here is an example segment;

`b'01\n\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00mv\xfe\x00'`

I need to make a series of changes, for example

`b'01\n\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00mv\xfe\x00'
 b'01\n\x04\x00\x00\x01\x00mv\xfe\x00'
 b'01\n\x00\x10\x00\x08\x00mv\xfe\x00'`

Doing this with sting manipulation would be straightforward, as I could concatenate each of the required components, but I am unsure of a way to get from

`'01\n\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00mv\xfe\x00'`

to

`b'01\n\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00mv\xfe\x00'`

Is the a way to do this or another way to solve this problem using python?

Thanks

Comment: Why don’t you use the same manipulations on the bytes? Most things should be supported. the only surprising and awkward feature that I personally consider a mistake is that foo[index] is an integer. Not a bytestring as it would be in string land.

Comment: Is there a way to concatenate them? The length of them would make that quite useful. How do I perform an equivalent operation?

Comment: How do you concatenation strings? With +, join of a list or formatting. The latter does not work. Both the others do.